# Magento 2 - How to add custom attribute in knockout "data-bind="html: 'Product Attribute : ' + product_sku "

Tags: magento2.4.1, knockout

I want to show my custom attribute on the wishlist sidebar section, how to add my custom attribute "brand & Size" attributes into this,

eg:

```
<div data-bind="html:product_brand "></div>
```

Brand is my attribute, its not showing,

```
 <div data-bind="html: product_price"></div>
```

price is showing, how to display my brand attribute.

I want to add **attribute : brand & size**

Answer (score 1):

To use any custom attribute in the knockout, you need to add them in `customerData`

Check Method `getItemData` of Class `Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist`,all the product attributes used in knockout part are defined here. You need to add your required attributes with key to the final returned array, to use it in phtml.

Comment: path : C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist.php  code: https://codeshare.io/2KzpMK where i can include my brand attribute.

Comment: in the same array where product_name is added,  Line no 154-171

Comment: 'product_name' => $product->getName(), how to add my brand attribute?

Comment: try this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Get-Manufacturer-name-on-a-category-page/td-p/109875

Comment: is it right https://codeshare.io/5XkV1k

Comment: you need to confirm variables and your attribute code, which you need to show, Also I would not suggest to make changes in core class, intead override them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122806/discussion-between-zus-and-piyush).